# Prove this equation

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, stochastic-analysis

I'm taking a course on stochastic analysis.  I'm stuck on the very first problem of the lecture notes:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{\lambda}{n} + o(n^{-1})\right)^n = \exp(\lambda)$

Prior to the problem, the lecturer mentioned infinitesimal functions and introduced the Taylor series.  I'm not sure how they are useful in proving the above, however.

I thought about taking the log of both sides:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} n\log \left(1+\frac{\lambda}{n} + o(n^{-1})\right) = \lambda$

then substituting $m=n^{-1}$ to get:

$\lim_{m \to 0} m^{-1} \log \left(1+\lambda m + o(m)\right) = \lambda$

I'm lost on where to go next.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: As $m$ approaches 0, you can write $\log(1 + x)$ in terms of its taylor expansion.

Comment: Where does $x$ come from?

Comment: $x$ in this case is $\lambda m + o(m)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$A = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{\lambda}{n} + f(n)\right)^n$$
where $f(n) = o(n^{-1})$.

Then $$\log(A) = n\log\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{\lambda}{n} + f(n)\right)\right)$$

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} |f(n)| \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\epsilon/n = 0$. It follows that

$$\log(A) = \log \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^n\right)$$

and therefore:

$$ A = \exp(\lambda)$$

Comment: Could you explain the reasoning behind the final step (the "therefore")?  It's not obvious to me why $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^n = \exp(\lambda)$.

Comment: This holds by definition. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition

Comment: Ah, that's the part I was missing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can show and use the following inequality:
$$\forall t\geqslant 0,\quad t-\frac{t^2}2\leqslant \log(1+t)\leqslant t.$$
It's classical and actually, it's a bound on the Taylor's remainder. But we can prove it directly.